# mysqli_multi_query fails on multiple inserts

Tags: php, mysqli, syntax-error, insert-into, mysqli-multi-query

Greetings, I'm having the following issue:

When I attempt to execute several INSERT INTO queries using the mysqli_multi_query function, none of them are executed and I receive a standard "You have an error in your SQL syntax" error, but when I take the exact same string I passed to the function and paste into PHPMyAdmin and execute it, it works flawlessly!

Here are the queries I am attempting to execute:

```
INSERT INTO production VALUES( 120, 103, 10, 0, 0 ); 
INSERT INTO production VALUES( 120, 107, 5, 1, 0 ); 
INSERT INTO production VALUES( 120, 106, 7, 2, 0 ); 
INSERT INTO production VALUES( 120, 103, 20, 0, 1 );
```

These are in a single string, separated by a space after the semicolon.

Here's what I do in the code:

```
$querytext = $queries // Get all the queries
$query_result = mysqli_multi_query( $this->_connection, $querytext );

if( mysqli_errno($this->_connection) > 0)
    echo mysqli_error($this->_connection);

var_dump( $querytext );
var_dump( $query_result );
```

Executing this code results in:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO production VALUES( 120, 107, 5, 1, 0 ); INSERT INTO production VALUE' at line 1
>
> string(210) "INSERT INTO production VALUES( 120, 103, 10, 0, 0 ); INSERT INTO production VALUES( 120, 107, 5, 1, 0 ); INSERT INTO production VALUES( 120, 106, 7, 2, 0 ); INSERT INTO production VALUES( 120, 103, 20, 0, 1 ); "
>
> bool(false)

If you would like to test this behaviour out yourself, here is the `production` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `production` (
`colonyID` INT NOT NULL ,
`resource_type_being_built` INT NOT NULL ,
`amount_requested` INT NOT NULL ,
`build_list_position` INT NOT NULL ,
`production_number` INT NOT NULL ,
INDEX (  `colonyID` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Am I overlooking something or is this simply odd behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure line breaks are allowed in between queries?

Comment: See "These are in a single string, separated by a space after the semicolon.": No line breaks are actually in the string, I just prettied it up for the browser.

ajreal's suggestion fixed it, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this to minimize chances of error

```
INSERT INTO production VALUES (120,103,10,0,0), 
(120,107,5,1,0), (120,106,7,2,0), (120, 103,20,0,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the semicolon for the last entry.

```
INSERT INTO production VALUES( 120, 103, 10, 0, 0 ); 
INSERT INTO production VALUES( 120, 107, 5, 1, 0 ); 
INSERT INTO production VALUES( 120, 106, 7, 2, 0 ); 
INSERT INTO production VALUES( 120, 103, 20, 0, 1 )
```

Comment: No dice, still get the same error. Thanks for the suggestion, though :)