# What is the maximum number of queries in a multi query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

is there a maximum number of queries when run a multiquery using php?

```
  $conn = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
    }  

   $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS......";
   $sql .= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS......";
   $sql .= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS......";
   $sql .= "INSERT ......";
   $sql .= "INSERT ......";
    <and so on>
    mysqli_autocommit($conn, false);
    mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_rollback($conn);
```

Comment: just for curious and my code seem to freez after a few querryies.but if i run them individually thecode works

Comment: And what happens once you test this code?

Comment: some front querries works.but some in end dont work.i try to run them in seperated querry in another php file and it works

Answer (score 0):

I don't now wheter the PHP function [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) is implemented by using the multiquery possibilitie s of the [MySQL API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html) or if this splits the statements on the PHP side.

But you could try raising `net_buffer_length but` and `max_allowed_packet` in your `my.cnf`. But I was under the impression that these were per statement buffers.

To be clear to people that stumble here, not out of curiosity as the OP did, but because they bumped into the maximum: There usually are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4451885/383793) to do [many INSERTs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5071591/383793).

Comment: I know this thread is a bit old, but looking through the PHP source (5.6) mysqli_multi_query function calls mysql_real_query and does not buffer the query requests internally.